# Add a user without password but with SSH and public key

Tags: ssh, password, authentication, useradd

I want to add a user to Red Hat Linux that will not use a password for logging in, but instead use a public key for ssh. This would be on the command line.

Comment: useradd --password-disable and adduser --password disable.  I've looked at the options for both and don't see password disable as an option for either.

Comment: Do you know how to set up an ssh key login in general? I think the account just needs to not be locked, which would imply that there is some password active. It can be some long password that no one actually knows.

Comment: I have the key and know that I need to create the folder under user's directory and paste public portion there.  I can try that way, but thought that I needed to disable the user password too.

Comment: Rather than make another post showing you how to add a user, I agree with Lambert. You need to focus specifically on the part of this task you are having trouble with. If you don't know how to even add a user, you should start small and work your way up. I believe you only need to create the user, don't set any password, and put their key in /home/username/.ssh/authorized_keys.

Answer (score 89):

Start with creating a user:

```
useradd -m -d /home/username -s /bin/bash username
```

Create a key pair from the client which you will use to `ssh` from:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Copy the public key `/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` onto the RedHat host into `/home/username/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Set correct permissions on the files on the RedHat host:

```
chown -R username:username /home/username/.ssh
chmod 700 /home/username/.ssh
chmod 600 /home/username/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Ensure that Public Key authentication is enabled on the RedHat host:

```
grep  PubkeyAuthentication /etc/ssh/sshd_config
#should output:
PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

If not, change that directive to yes and restart the `sshd` service on the RedHat host.

From the client start an `ssh` connection:

```
ssh username@redhathost
```

It should automatically look for the key `id_rsa` in `~/.ssh/`. You can also specify an identity file using:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa username@redhathost
```

Comment: Actually I did not forget about the password lock. Since I simply did not set it the password of the newly created user is automatically locked.

Comment: use RSA instead of DSA

Comment: you realize the "ssh-keygen -t dsa" command will create keys for the current user, it might replace your own keys

Comment: Use `ssh-keygen -t ed25519` instead since this is the most recommended public-key algorithm available today

Comment: I make a mistake of thinking "into `authorized_keys`" meant that `authorized_keys` was a folder. It's actually a file! Hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 31):

On Ubuntu you can add the user with:

```
adduser --disabled-password <username>
```

Then create `.ssh/authorized_keys` file in their home directory with their public key.

Answer (score 13):

You could use:

```
usermod --lock <username>
```

From the man page:

> Lock a user's password. This puts a '!' in front of the encrypted password, effectively disabling the password. You can't use this option with -p or -U.  Note: if you wish to lock the account (not only access with a password), you should also set the EXPIRE_DATE to 1.

Answer (score 3):

Complete script (`<SSH_PUB_KEY>` is in format of `ssh-rsa …`):

```bash
NEW_USER=newuser

sudo adduser --disabled-password "$NEW_USER"
sudo -i -u "$NEW_USER"

# now you are under the new user's shell
cd
mkdir -p .ssh
chmod 0700 .ssh
echo "<SSH_PUB_KEY>" > .ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
```

I was looking for a script that I can fearlessly run creating a new user with proper SSH permissions, so if you do too, I believe this should help you :)